# Refresh website with timer in C# - CefSharp

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I want to create a bot for the website, this site add a part with an *id*, i want when the part add to site click on this part button.
My code check a website to find this *id*, until this *id* is not found the website is refreshing and when *id* found, click on the *button* in website.

This is my code:

```
public ChromiumWebBrowser browser;

public void InitBrowser()
{
    timer.Stop();
    browser.Reload();

    browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
    {
        //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
        if (args.Frame.IsMain)
        {
            var pageQueryScript = @"
            (function(){
                var selection = document.querySelector('#test');
                if (selection !== null) {
                    return '1';
                }
            })()";
            var scriptTask = browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(pageQueryScript);
            scriptTask.ContinueWith(a =>
            {
                if (a.Result.Success && a.Result.Result != null)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    var loginScript = @"document.querySelector('button').click();";
                    browser.EvaluateScriptAsync(loginScript).ContinueWith(b =>
                    {
                        timer.Stop();
                        Console.Write("*");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    timer.Start();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.Start();
}

public Form1()
{
    Cef.Initialize(new CefSettings());
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("file:///G:/2.html");
    this.Controls.Add(browser);
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    browser.Height = 500;
    browser.Width = 500;
    browser.Location = new Point(0, 0);

    InitializeComponent();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InitBrowser();

}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Start();
}
```

It work correctly **but it click on the button number of website refresh** i want click on this button one time.
how can i fix this problem.

Comment: honestly i dont understand your problem, is your code refresing the webpage several times?

Comment: @nalnpir yes,it refreshing the webpage until the webpage change and find *id*, when the *id* found, it click several times on the button. it must be click one time.

Comment: One bug i can think of is that you are constantly adding a new event to your FrameLoadEnd, that thing should be only done once, because if not you are subscribing that anonymous task each time your timer ticks